# How do I get more information from an additional column if the first one does not have it?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I would just like to say that I'm very new to VBA and more complicated formulas so all the help will be appreciated! Thank you!

To clarify a bit more with the title.  I currently have a Macro that is reading a formula to give me information from another worksheet. I'll give an example of the formula that is working:

```
=IF(A2 = ""No Specific Program"", A2,IF(F2 = """",""No PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,F2),....!$C:$I,4,FALSE),""NO DATA"")))
```

This is the original formula that I'm using to get the information, column A is my **Parts owned by Program**, And my column B is the actual **Program**. So when I run the Macro it does give me most of the information, but when it runs into **"No Specific Program"** even when there is something for Column B showing what program the part is in, it will give me **No specific Program**.

Also for reference the F2 it is Concatenating is a PIN number which will help determine who owns the part.

I've been stumped on this trying to get the code to work and I've tried place **THEN** and **ELSE** within the statement and it just gives a **FALSE** statement

EDIT:

The Code above works, it's when I use this version of the Code:

```
=IF(A2 = ""No Specific Program"",THEN,IF(F2 = """",""No PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,F2),'.....'!$C:$I,4,FALSE),""NO DATA"",Else,IF(A2 = ""No Specific Program"",THEN,IF(F2 = """",""No PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,F2),'.....'!$C:$I,4,FALSE),""NO DATA"")))))
```

I get the False or errors when I try different variations. Here is an example of the columns. Column A is where I have the original formula reading from, but then it says No Specific Program, while Column B shows the Program. So I'm trying to get the formula to read that as well as column A to capture all the information I need :

[Columns Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ZLt.png)

EDIT:

It starts breaking after the **ELSE** statement.

Edit:

> =IF(A2 = ""No Specific Program"",
>
> IF(F2 = """",""No PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B2,F2),'\NW\Data\TechIntegration\Sustaining
>   Team\Data
>   Mining\DataMining[GAD_PIN_TABLE.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$I,5,FALSE),
>   ""NO GAD
>   DATA"",
>
> IF(F2 = """",""No
>   PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,F2),'\NW\Data\TechIntegration\Sustaining
>   Team\Data
>   Mining\DataMining[GAD_PIN_TABLE.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$I,5,FALSE),""NO GAD
>   DATA"")))))

Just trying to make it easier to see the formula.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Data samples (even screenshots) are really going to help us help you with this. Also, posting the actual VBA code you have written thus far.

Comment: Break the formula up into it's components and determine which piece is not outputting the correct response, then migrate it back to VBA.

Comment: @CodyG.So it's breaking after the ELSE statement, I'm probably not implementing it correctly.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've edited the original post. The formula I'm using in the code is the only issue after multiple tests.  Everything else works fine, I'm just trying to expand the amount of information this formula captures. I've been trying to solve it but I'm stumped.

Comment: its actually very hard to read what you are trying to attempt, as you do not post the formula in valid excel formula syntax, or valid VBA syntax. I think I may see an error, but it's very difficult to decipher. Can you edit it to one or the other valid syntax, then we can help fix it much easier. You may also benefit from `IF(AND(arg1,arg2),"Y","N")` type of structure as well, or `IF(OR(arg1,arg2),"Y","N")`

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying, but I just got the code to work

Answer (score 0):

I'd split this down to make it simpler to follow, use a holding cell then refer to that in your top formula (The one you know works already)

Stick this in another column, say Z for example, then everywhere you refer to A2 in your working formula, change it to Z2

```
=IF(A2=""No Specific Program"",IF(B2=""No Specific Program"",""No Specific Program"",B2),A2)
```

This will only give you "No specific program" if both a2 **and** b2 contain "No specific program" which I think is what you're after. In your second example in the columns example link, it will return NG